# C# and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel Find all cells merged with given cell

Tags: c#, excel, interop

Given a single cell, I want to know the range of cells that are merged with it.

I have looked at this question:
[how to detect merged cells in c# using MS interop excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31069790/how-to-detect-merged-cells-in-c-sharp-using-ms-interop-excel)

But that is to tell you if a given range has merged cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `Cell` type. A single cell is a `Range`, just like lots of cells.

Therefore the same methods apply: `YourCell.MergeCells` is a boolean property equal to true for merge ranges and `YourCell.MergeArea` is the said merged range.

`MergeArea` always returns a value. If the cell is merged with no other cells, then it returns the cell (again typed `Range`) itself.

Comment: MergeArea is exactly what I needed. Thank you!